# Viewpager value doesnt change while getting the postion from the listview

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Lets say this is the start page where the user selects the page he wants to see

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(
                ) {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int position, long arg3) {
                        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor   editor = preferences.edit();
                        editor.putInt("Position_content",position);
                        editor.commit();
                        Intent newpage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);    
                        startActivity(newpage);
                        }});
```

and this is my Mainactivity.class

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        MyFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fm);
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        content_selection_page = sharedPref.getInt("Position_content",0);
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor   editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("final_Position_content",content_selection_page);
        editor.commit();    }
```

This is MyFragmentAdapter.java

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 52;

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);  }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {     
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putInt("current_page", arg0+1);
        myFragment.setArguments(data);
        return myFragment;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {     
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {        
        return "Page " + ( position + 1 );  
    }   

}
```

This is the Fragment.java

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle data = getArguments();
        //** Getting integer data of the key current_page from the bundle *//*
        mCurrentPage = data.getInt("current_page", 0);
        sharedPref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        content_selection_page = sharedPref.getInt("final_Position_content",0);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout, container,false);             
        TextView sub = (TextView ) v.findViewById(R.id.sub1);
        TextView sub1 = (TextView ) v.findViewById(R.id.sub2);
        TextView hd = (TextView ) v.findViewById(R.id.head);
        content_selection_page++;  //doesnt work


        switch(content_selection_page){
                switch stmts.....
                }
                return v;
                }
```

**The Real Problem** Now the problem is the user selects a choice through a list and the position is got to the switch case in the fragment.java now the viewpager doesnt seem to work. suppose if i click the list item 4 it takes me to the 3rd page and when i slide it slides **but** it still is in the same page, how do i make it such that if i slide once it has to increment the page everytime.
[image: Diagramatically]
 instead of Content 2 i keep getting content 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to setCurrentPage in ViewPager according to user selection & how do I know which list item called the activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368242/how-to-setcurrentpage-in-viewpager-according-to-user-selection-how-do-i-know-w)

that link helped me :)
looks like i missed
`mPager.setCurrentItem(position);`